How is Miles’s glitching related to his limited understanding of his place in the Spider-Society?
At Spider-HQ, Miguel invites the Spider-gang, and Gwen introduces them to the Spider-Society. The large number of Spider-People surprises Hobie and Miles. Gwen explains that many are part-time members:

Hobie (to Gwen): Gwendy, how much have you told him? Hmm? About his place in all this?
Gwen: A little.

Miles glitches behind them.

HOBIE: Maybe not enough.

How is Miles’s glitching related to his limited understanding of his place in the Spider-Society?

All Spidermen Glitch when outside of their own universe unless they have a special device that blocks the glitching.
Those who join the Spider-Society get such a device, but Miles never got one so he "doesn't belong" amongst the others.

The connection between Miles's glitching and his limited understanding of the Spider-Society becomes clear in the subsequent dialogue:

Spider-Woman: Here.
Miles: My own watch!
Spider-Woman: It's a day pass. This just keeps you from…
[Miles glitches]
…doing that.

Spider-Woman hands Miles a "day pass" bracelet device that prevents him from glitching. "Maybe not enough" refers to Miles's "limited understanding" / lack of awareness about this technology. The Spider-Society has developed tools to manage the interdimensional glitch effects experienced by Spider-People when they're outside their home universes. Miles, being new to the group, was unfamiliar with this technology.

It's not. All beings will glitch outside their own realities, as seen with the renessiance Vulture in the opening fight sequence, unless the glitching is stopped technologically via the bands or watches. Miles' understanding of the situation has no relevance to when or why he glitches.
The timing of Miles' glitches to the points just after it's discussed is simply a story telling mechanism to reinforce the connection. And it fits the Spiderman irreverent comedic style.

It's also worth noting that Miles has been specifically excluded from the society due to Miguel's view of him as an inherent anomaly - while his glitching isn't directly related to him not "being in on the loop", his nature as an outsider is thematically connected; he's one big "glitch" in the model of what "a spiderman" should be to Miguel.
